# Create show-menu in powershell depending on variables

Tags: powershell, menu

I want to create a menu with show-menu that will depend on what is present on the computer.

I want to list in the menu usernames available on c:\users\ (based on the folders names).

For example :
in c:\users
there is folder nammed :

```
homer.simpson
lisa.simpson
bart.simpson
```

and with show-menu ask the user to choose one of them by typing 1 for homer.simpson 2 for lisa.simpson etc ..

How can i do it ?

Thank you in advance !

EDIT : Code

```
$users = Get-ChildItem "$env:SystemDrive\Users"| ForEach-Object { $_.Name }

foreach ($user in $user)   {

$user
$num++ 

New-Variable -Name "a$num" -Value $user
#Get-Variable -Name "$user$i" 

}



function Show-Menu
{
     param (
           [string]$Title = 'Please select an user'
     )
     cls
     Write-Host "================ $Title ================"

     Write-Host "1: $a1"
     Write-Host "2: $a2"
     Write-Host "3: $a3"
     Write-Host "Q: $a4"
}


do
{
     Show-Menu
     $input = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
     switch ($input)
     {
           '1' {
                cls
                'You chose option #1'
           } '2' {
                cls
                'You chose option #2'
           } '3' {
                cls
                'You chose option #3'
           } 'q' {
                return
           }
     }
     pause
}
until ($input -eq 'q')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (based on [Show-Menu by Adam Bertram](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-build-an-interactive-menu-with-powershell/)):

```
function Show-Menu
{
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'My Menu'
    )
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "================ $Title ================"

    $Menu = @{}

    (Get-ChildItem C:\Users).Name | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 1} { 

        Write-Host "$_`: Press '$i' for this option." 
        $Menu.add("$i",$_)
        $i++
    }

    Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."

    $Selection = Read-Host "Please make a selection"

    if ($Selection -eq 'Q') { Return } Else { $Menu.$Selection }

}

$UserSelection = Show-Menu -Title 'Local Users'
```

Per the comments, uses `(Get-ChildItem C:\Users).Name` to get the list of user folder names. These are then piped to a `ForEach-Object` loop which starts by initilizing a counter variable `$i` as 1.

In the loop it prints out the name of each file (now represented as `$_` which is the automatic variable for the current item in the pipeline) and uses the counter variable to display the numbered options. It also puts each number/name pair in a hashtable named `$Menu` which is then used as a lookup when the selection is entered via `Read-Host`.

The selected option is returned to the `$UserSelection` variable.

Comment: Thanks, just, you force the title of the show-menu with -Title but you already set the title on the line 4.

Comment: Line 4 is a default value for $Title, but we then override it when calling the function. Obviously you should adapt the code to your needs (the only reason for having $title as a parameter is to make the code more reusable).

Answer (score 0):

AHA! I figured it out! :)

```
function Show-Menu
{
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'My Menu'
    )
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "================ $Title ================"

    $Menu = @{}

    (Get-ChildItem C:\Users).Name | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 1} { 

        Write-Host "$_`: Press '$i' for this option." 
        $Menu.add("$i",$_)
        $i++
    }

    Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."

    $Selection = Read-Host "Please make a selection"

    if ($Selection -eq 'Q') { Return } Else { $Menu.$Selection }

}
#$UserSelection = Show-Menu -Title 'Local Users' 
#(Get-ChildItem C:\Users).Name
$userinput = Show-Menu -Title 'Local Users'
(Get-ChildItem C:\users\$userinput\ntuser.dat -Force | select @{e={(Split-path $_.Directory -Leaf)}},last* | sort lastwritetime -Descending)
```