# Get files of parent directory with foreach

Tags: php

If I have a directory like such "/personal/private/perfection"
Can I get it's files using foreach and be able to output their contents using file_get_contents? If not, please say a better way.
My current code is:

```
foreach("/personal/private/perfection" as $file) {
    echo file_get_contents($file . "\n");
}
```

Comment: You could reuse this script. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118493/create-show-menu-in-powershell-depending-on-variables/46118757?noredirect=1#comment79201244_46118757 Axel

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have done some research. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). There are _plenty_ of guides about listing files in folders with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the `glob()` function :

```
foreach(glob("/personal/private/perfection/../*") as $file) {
    echo file_get_contents($file);
}
```

http://php.net/glob